# Are there any physical phenomena that destroy information?

Tags: black-hole, cosmology

Are there physical phenomena, such as wave function collapse or black holes, which irrevocably destroy information about their prior states?

Comment: It sounds like you already know about the potential scenarios where information could possibly be destroyed since you listed them as examples in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the current questions of cosmology/physics.  So far all evidence points to the negative inside a black hole so far as quantum numbers go, but it's not clear what you're considering as "prior state."

A simple counter-example is a camera. Once the photons are absorbed by the film or solid-state sensor, all phase information is lost.  Is that what you were looking for?